# What type of mysql join do I need in the following query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following tables:

```
platforms(id,platformname)
games(id,title,platformid)
gameslists(id,memberid,gameid)
```

I would like to select all records from the games table, but exclude records where games.gameid is present in gameslists for a specific member. So in plain English: select all records from the games table except for those where the gameid is present in gameslists table where the memberid equals 999 (memberid will come from the session). I also need the platform name, but I think that's a simple inner join.

I tried this, and other variations but to no avail!

```
SELECT DISTINCT games.id, platforms.platformname, gameslists.gameid
FROM games
INNER JOIN platforms ON games.platformid = platforms.id
INNER JOIN gameslists ON games.id = gameslists.gameid
WHERE platformid = 1 and gameslists.memberid <> 999
ORDER BY games.releasedate DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL

```
   SELECT g.*
     FROM GAMES g
LEFT JOIN GAMESLISTS gl ON gl.gameid  = g.id
                       AND gl.memberid = ?
    WHERE gl.id IS NULL
```

### Using NOT IN

```
SELECT g.*
  FROM GAMES g
 WHERE g.id NOT IN (SELECT gl.gameid 
                      FROM GAMESLISTS gl
                     WHERE gl.memberid = ?)
```

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT g.*
  FROM GAMES g
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM GAMESLISTS gl
                   WHERE gl.gameid = g.id
                     AND gl.memberid = ?)
```

### Summary

In MySQL, the [LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the most efficient means of getting a list based on what to exclude, but only if the columns being compared are not nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) (the values in the join criteria can't be null).  [Otherwise, the NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are more efficient](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

### Conclusion

Because of the foreign keys, it's unlikely the columns compared will be NULL so use the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL.  But be aware that you don't need to use JOINs specifically for excluding data.

Comment: Thank you for this through explanation! It's extremely helpful going forward, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this guide](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) from Stack Overflow's very own Jeff Atwood